# How can I get the vk user id using kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, vk, vk-sdk

I want to make a "share vk" button, for this I use an http request https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post . But it needs a user ID. How can I get it? Or is there another way to post on the vk wall?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to know how to get the parameter you need - is to ask their [support](https://dev.vk.com/support)